# Vignere encryption code java

Tags: java, encryption

I am trying to write code to encrypt a text based on a Vignere cipher text array and this is what I wrote:

```
        String key = "WORKS";
        String text = "COMPLETE";
        char[] cipherText = new char[text.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < array.length; k++){
                if(key.length() > text.length())
                    if(i < key.length())
                        if(key.charAt(i) == array[i][0])
                            if(text.charAt(k) == array[0][k])
                                cipherText[i] = array[i][k];
                else if(text.length() > key.length())
                    if(i < text.length())
                        if(key.charAt(i) == array[i][0])
                            if(text.charAt(k) == array[0][k])
                                cipherText[i] = array[i][k];
            }
```

and finally I print the `cipherText` `char` array using `println`. Unfortunately, it does not work even though I am sure that my code is correct. It just doesn't show me anything, and of course the "key" and "text" are entered by user but I am just trying it here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should always use braces in your code for `if` statements so that you know whether the bits you are expecting to be in the if block really are in the `if` block. Otherwise your else will be parsed in a completely different block which isn't the one you think it is.

Comment: Oh, what a mistake. Thank you. It still doesn't work, it says index out of range. I will try solving it. Thank you again.